# Increment value for entire parts tray (slots in tray) if slot = 0

Tags: mysql

Please excuse my ignorance of MySQL.  I've tried searching, though I must not have hit on the right search criteria.

I have a parts cabinets, in each cabinet there are three slots, each slot contains a parts ID.  Some of those slots were ID'd as slot 0 upon entry rather than slot 1.  I'm hoping to get assistance on a query that will find all those trays that have a "slot 0" and increment those slots within that tray by 1.  So instead of `slot` = 0, 1, 2 .. it would be `slot` = 1, 2, 3
But again, some were entered correctly and they are `slot` = 1, 2, 3 already.

Here is the schema

------ cabinet 1
---- drawer 1
-- slot 0
-- slot 1
-- slot 2
---- drawer 2
-- slot 1
-- slot 2
-- slot 3
---- drawer 3
-- slot 1
-- slot 2
-- slot 3
---- drawer 4
-- slot 0
-- slot 1
-- slot 2
---- drawer 5
-- slot 1
-- slot 2
-- slot 3
etc.

So drawer 1 and drawer 4 slots start at 0, where they should have start with slot 1

That is the type of query I am in need of please.  I greatly appreciate the assistance!

** I put the below in a comment before, though comments dont allow HTML, I am not just new to MySQL but stackoverflow as well, my apologies.

It's only one table. db1.drawercontents

drawer, slot, partid
An example:
 
1, 1, 4516
 
1, 2, 5567
 
1, 3, 7786
 
2, 0, 6422
 
2, 1, 4311
 
2, 2, 8112
 
3, 1, 7655
 
3, 2, 1341
 
3, 3, 4987
 

 
 
slot should begin with 1 vice 0, but drawer 2 has its slot beginning at 0, rather than 1 However, there are 1570 drawers, otherwise I would just adjust it by hand.  I hope this helps.

EDIT: This is the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE drawercontents
(
  drawer int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  slot int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  partid int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (drawer,'slot'),
  UNIQUE KEY drawer (drawer,partid),
  KEY partid (partid)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Could you post the table definition? Copy the output from `show create table ...` in place of what you have above.

Comment: | drawercontents | CREATE TABLE `drawercontents` (
`drawer` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`slot` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT `0`,
`partid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT `0`,
PRIMARY KEY (`drawer`,'`slot'`),
UNIQUE KEY `drawer` (`drawer`,`partid`),
KEY `partid` (`partid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |